# React Native UI Not updating after AsyncStorage fetches + setStates?

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to build a settings screen for my react native app. I'm using AsyncStorage to save the data. Here is how I am set up currently.

State has default values initially. Anytime one of the settings components is updated, it will throw the data into AsyncStorage, as well as update the state to update UI and show the correct value for each setting.

The problem is updating the state upon app reload so all settings components are reflected as they were when the user left them. Every time I recompile, the settings go back to the initial default.

Here is the code in which I am trying to achieve this with:

```
async componentWillMount(){
    settings = 
    [
      'buildtol',
      'decimal_places',
      'response_time',
      'device_number'
    ]

    await AsyncStorage.multiGet(settings, (err, stores)=> {
      for(i = 0; i < stores.length; ++i){
        let key = stores[i][0];
        let val = stores[i][1];
        try{
        this.setState({key : val})
        console.log('key: ' + key + ' val: ' + val);
        }catch(e){
          console.log(e);
        }

      }
    })

  }
```

This works if I do a single get, instead of a multiget. Once I try to do more like above, it won't reflect the changes in the UI.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use async-await when you are using callbacks?

Comment: No real reason besides that someone suggested it on a thread for a problem sorta similar, so i thought I'd throw a hail mary and try it out.

Comment: When you do multiget do you get the correct stores? What I mean is are you sure everything other than setstate is working fine?

Comment: Yeah, my console.log line shows the correct keys/values. So it is fetching it correctly. Just not updating the state correctly.

I think I may just be going about this task incorrectly as it is. I should probably be loading in the values while the app loads up, and then pass them as props to the screen. Still slightly unsure on how the design philosophy should go for this type of task.